# SELECT 180 records took 2 seconds

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

My table is simple:

`` CREATE TABLE `od_form_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `formid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items` mediumtext,
  `template` mediumtext,
  `draftid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=420 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT ``

And it only contains `180` rows:

`mysql> select count(*) from od_form_items;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      180 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

The longest string is just `26314` bytes:

`mysql> select length(items) as a from qiban.od_form_items order by a desc limit 1;
+-------+
| a     |
+-------+
| 26314 |
+-------+
1 rows in set (0.01 sec)
mysql> select length(template) as a from qiban.od_form_items order by a desc limit 1;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
| 6556 |
+------+
1 rows in set (0.01 sec)`

But in mysql slow_log, it took over `2` seconds to select all records:

`` mysql> select start_time, query_time, sql_text from mysql.slow_log order by start_time desc limit 10;
+---------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
| start_time          | query_time | sql_text                                   |
+---------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
| 2017-11-24 10:34:40 | 00:00:02   | SELECT * FROM `od_form_items`              +---------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
1 rows in set (0.01 sec) ``

How should I optimize it? What mysql parameter should I check? Thanks!

Comment: Did you output the full 180 records to the terminal? I imagine it took 2 seconds for the client to pull the full 180 & display them on the screen, rather than 2 seconds for the RDBMS to fetch the resultset

Comment: No, actually that SQL statement is run by Java to load the records into memcache.

Comment: i doubt this can be optimized.. TEXT column are stored separted from record.. So looking up a TEXT column would require a random disk I/O request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an ordinary spinning drive, you can get about 100 IOPs.  If all 180 rows needed to reach off-row to get `items` and none needed for `template`, then that is 180 + miscellany to get `SELECT *` 180 times.  That's about 2 seconds.

SSD drives would be faster.

Compressing, in the client, those two columns, then storing them in BLOBs, would shrink things a bunch.  This would probably lead to fewer IOPs.

It seems like populating memcached would be a one-time action, so the 2 seconds would not be a big deal?

Comment: I am thinking of to change the `text` columns to `varchar(65535)` columns.

Comment: That won't help.  Only 'short' `VARCHARs` are handled more efficiently than `TEXT`.  ("Short" varies with the context.)